# Changing variable names after importing functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, import

I have a master .py file that has a collection of all functions that I need to use for various applications. However, each application needs the variable names in the functions to be changed after import.

May I know what’s the best way to modify functions after import?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide more info? Why do you need to change variable names inside a function? Do you mean local variables, global variables or class attributes?

Comment: Thanks @VascoLudovico for helping. I'm doing data validation using pandas, and different datasets have different column names for the same entity , Eg: A person's account code is called "CUSTCODE" in one and "ACCNo" in another. I've based my master function file with the former, so I want flexibility to modify the functions after import for each dataset (each dataset validation will have a unique .py file). Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but can't that labels be args of the function itself? That way each time you call it you can specify with label you want to use.